# Glassfish4.1 + Hibernate + persistence.xml = Exception

Tags: hibernate, jpa, glassfish, persistence.xml

I'm trying to use hibernate as JTA provider in glassfish. For that purpose i created sample bean

```html
@Entity
@Table
public class BlogEntry implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String content;

    <... setters and getters ...>
}
```

Then i defined jdbc pool and resource in glassfish 4.1 admin panel as MySql connection. Named resource as JSFDemoJNDI. Then i created persistence.xml like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>JSFDemoJNDI</jta-data-source>
        <class>ru.windwail.BlogEntry</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                      value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

And created simple servlet to test it out:

```html
@WebServlet(name = "TestHibernateJTA", urlPatterns = {"/jta"})
public class TestJTA extends HttpServlet {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPU")
    EntityManager em;

    @Resource
    UserTransaction ut;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        BlogEntry be = new BlogEntry();
        be.setContent("some content");

        try {
            ut.begin();
            em.persist(be);
            ut.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet SearchFacadeClient</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Done without exceptions! Yarrrr!</h1>");
            out.println("<br/><a href='/'>Back</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

So when i ran it i've got strange exception:

```html
[2015-02-06T03:40:22.081+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=32 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1423183222081] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[TestHibernateJTA]: Servlet.service() for servlet TestHibernateJTA threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of ru.windwail.BlogEntry.id
    at ru.windwail.TestJTA.doGet(TestJTA.java:36)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of ru.windwail.BlogEntry.id
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:287)
    at ru.windwail.TestJTA.doGet(TestJTA.java:33)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of ru.windwail.BlogEntry.id
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4746)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:511)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field ru.windwail.BlogEntry.id to ru.windwail.BlogEntry
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:57)
    ... 43 more
]]
```

Then i tried to use eclipselink in persistence.xml like this:

```html
    <persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>JSFDemoJNDI</jta-data-source>
        <class>ru.windwail.BlogEntry</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

And bam! It's working!... So problem not in code, seems its problem in hibernate jpa ? i saw few similar questions , but no solution there. 
`
Here is my simplest project
https://github.com/icetusk/testjpa
(sorry for commiting intellij idea folders :)

Maybe hibernate jpa libs made for jboss ? Seems i will use eclipselink... hope it integrates with spring well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't really understand what was the problem. But in ear build hibernate works well. Also i see that there are bugs in new hibernate versions. Also hibernate is slower than eclipselink... so i decided to use latter.

Comment: did you figure it out? Having the same problem right now, dont know how to set hibernate as jpa provider for glassfish 4.1.0